# Sql server bulk load into a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to update a table in sql server 2008 along the lines of the Merge statement - delete, insert, updates. Table is 700k rows and I need users to still have read access to it assuming an isolation level of read committed.

I tried things like `ALTER TABLE table SET (LOCK_ESCALATION=DISABLE)` to no avail. I tested by doing a `select top 50000 *` from another window, obvious read uncommitted worked :). Is there anyway around this without changing the user's isolation level and retaining an 'all or nothing' transaction behaviour?

My current solution of a cursor that commits in batches of n may allow users to work but loses the transactional behaviour. Perhaps I could just make the bulk update fast enough to always be less than 30 seconds (for timeout). The problem is the user's target db's are on very slow machines with only 512mb ram. Not sure the processor but assume it is really slow and I don't have access to them at this time!

I created a test that causes an update statement to need to run against all 700k rows:
I tried an update with a left join on my dev box (quite fast) and it was 17 seconds
The merge statement was 10 seconds
The FORWARD ONLY cursor was slower than both

These figures are acceptable on my machine but I would feel more comfortable if I could get the query time down to less than 5 seconds before allowing locks.

Any ideas on preventing any locking on the table/rows or making it faster still?

Comment: What about read committed snapshot? Or having the app query a proxy view that has a `SNAPSHOT` hint.

Comment: @usr I can't really change the user's isolation level or mess with that query I'm afraid

Comment: Regardless of the way you update, the log file will grow unless you use small batches and change the recovery level to simple or take a ton of log backups with full recovery.  Can this be done on a down period so that transaction isolation is less of an issue?  Also, 512 MB of RAM, OMG!  Time to add memory, what OS is this running on??

Comment: @Jaycee this is a database option. No app changes.

Comment: @CRAFTYDBA Windows xp, but moving to windows 7 at some point

Comment: @usr Can you elaborate please?

Comment: @Jaycee https://www.google.com/webhp?complete=1&hl=en&gws_rd=ssl#complete=1&hl=en&q=sql+server+READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT

Comment: @usr The question remains unanswered however...

Comment: @Jaycee I assume that you are familiar with that option now and understand what it means. No point in me repeating information that is already available to you. Enable that option. This will make the app use snapshot isolation instead of read committed. This eliminates blocking and gives perfect read consistency. That should solve your problem.

Comment: @USR Thanks, I do appreciate this comment and solution, but I cannot change the target DB, the DB is copied on thousands of boxes across a large business. Changing the config at db level is not an option for me, I have no control over this, they are stuck at the default.

Comment: Are there any FKs referring to this table? Where is the new data coming from?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this table may be queried a lot but not updated much.  If it really is a true read-only table for everyone else, but you want to update it extremely quickly, you could create a script that uses this method (could even wrap it in a transaction, I believe, although it's probably unnecessary):

1. Make a copy of the table named TABLENAME_COPY
2. Update the copy table
3. Rename the original table to TABLENAME_ORIG
4. Rename the copy table to TABLENAME

You would only experience downtime in between steps 3 and 4, and a scripted table rename would probably be quicker than an update of so many rows.

This does all assume that no else can update the table while your process is running, but they will still be able to read it fully at any point except between 3 & 4

Comment: Don't forget to script your indexes and foreign key relationships also.